# Can't create External Files Dir in Android. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is present

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I tried using both my `ApplicationContext` and my calling `Service`'s `Context` to access the external directory. Unfortunately, it keeps returning `null`, and LogCat reports it was unable to create the external directory. I'm sure I have the `WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION` present, but it still won't work. My device is running API 10 (2.3.3) vanilla android. Any ideas?

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="droid.signboard" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="SignboardApp">
    <receiver android:name=".ApplicationStarter">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            <action android:name="droid.signboard.LAUNCHER_START"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name=".view.Signboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".controller.MasterControllerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="droid.signboard.LAUNCH_SERVICE_FROM_ACTIVITY"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


</application>
</manifest>
```

and here's where the code messes up:

```
private boolean canWriteEx () {

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState ();

    if (state.equals (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Log.i (TAG, "Can write to external directory: "
                + context.getExternalFilesDir (null).getAbsolutePath ());
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.i (TAG, "Cannot write to external directory: "
                + context.getExternalFilesDir (null).getAbsolutePath ());
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code is a method of a `Runnable`, that is called by a `Service`. The constructor of the `Runnable` takes a `Context` as its parameter. That is the `Context` used by the code. The code throws an exception at the Log call that ***succeeds***, implying that external storage is present and available.

**UPDATES OF ATTEMPTED FIXES:**

A clean install doesn't work.
Reverting down to API 9 doesn't work, though it worked earlier.

Comment: Post your androidmanifest.xml file.

Comment: Post your code, and any relevant stack traces. without it all we can do is guess shots in the dark.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you calling context.getExternalFilesDir (null)? Tell us the purpose and we might aim you better. ALso, stack trace from your logcat would be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to download a file off the net, into my device's external storage dir. This will be executed by a service, and should run asynchronously from all the rest of the app. In order to do that, I assume I need a connection and access to external storage. I passed a `Context` to the `Runnable` that prepares the `DownloadManager.Request` to do these. I check external storage first, but it fails here, even if `Environment.getStorageState ()` works.

Comment: I've been seeing this problem as well, on 2.3.3 and on 4.0. Seems like the device gets into a state where it will continue returning null (or maybe empty string), and only a hard reset will fix it. The fact that it works most of the time makes me think my code/manifest are OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**FIXED**, but I don't really know why it works now. **I reboot the device**, then all of a sudden, it would work again; `Context#getExternalFilesDir ()` stopped returning `null`. Even though it works now (thanks and props to `The IT Crowd`'s Roy and Moss), should I report this to Google or something?

Comment: This works but comes back sometimes after clearing my app's data.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old thread but I just ran into the same problem and found the reason which I'm surprised is not more common.  I was trying to write to the external storage while my device was connected to computer/Eclipse.. and I was getting the following error,

> 06-25 16:16:09.565: W/ApplicationContext(4290): Unable to create external files directory
>   06-25 16:16:09.565: W/System.err(4290): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /full_archive.zip: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
>   06-25 16:16:09.565: W/System.err(4290):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
>   06-25 16:16:09.565: W/System.err(4290):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
>   06-25 16:16:09.565: W/System.err(4290):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
>   06-25 16:16:09.565: W/System.err(4290):     at com.seine.trophy.database.DownloaderThread.run(DownloaderThread.java:79)
>   06-25 16:16:09.573: W/System.err(4290): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
>   06-25 16:16:09.573: W/System.err(4290):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>   06-25 16:16:09.573: W/System.err(4290):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
>   06-25 16:16:09.573: W/System.err(4290):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
>   06-25 16:16:09.573: W/System.err(4290):     ... 3 more

This is from the Developer Guide...

> Caution: External storage can become unavailable if the user mounts the external storage on a computer ...

Simply detaching the phone from my computer/IDE solved the problem for me.

Comment: This was the answer I came up with as well. I can't believe this isn't a more common problem and isn't in ***big bold*** somewhere more accessible.

Comment: @ToddPainton I did not get this problem - perhaps you did not set developer options in settings? I use android 4.04 API 15. samsung S2.

Comment: Oh no that was set.  My solution eventually?  Unity.  I can't stand native android programming any longer.  And as an added plus?  I can compile the same code to Apple.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your AndroidManifest.xml. At least, thats what solved it for me.

Add the line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` before your `<application ...` line.

Comment: I am surprised there are 3 different root causes for this.

Comment: That's the strangest thing, I moved the permissions _before_ the application line and it works now. Did reboot inbetween but done that many times already. Thanks.

Comment: I was facing exact the same issue and this solution solved it for me, Thnx!